# Remote testing for Android and iOS using Flutter

Tags: testing, flutter, continuous-integration

I am using Flutter and want testers to remotely QA my app.
What are some viable options using CI/CD?
How would the testers install the app on their devices?

Comment: You may want to look into `TestMagic`. Its an app to distribute test builds. You can access and download latest CI/CD builds and also share downloadable links with the testers. More on it here : https://blog.codemagic.io/getting-started-with-testmagic/.   Hope it helps.